# C5.0 Machine Learning in R with 100% accuracy for test data

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree

I am doing a machine learning project and using a C5.0 decision tree to look at breast cancer data, to try and predict the diagnosis as malignant or benign. The dataset is one of the UCI Machine Learning datasets, and it is posted at this link: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Breast+Cancer+Wisconsin+%28Diagnostic%29.

I think my code is correct for the model, but whenever I run it for the test data, it is coming up as having 100% accuracy for this data. I am assuming that this means I am doing something wrong, but I am not sure as to what:

```
#Load Library
library(C50)
library(gmodels)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

#Import Data
setwd("C:\\Users\\Grant\\Downloads")
wdbc<-read.delim("C:\\Users\\Grant\\Downloads\\wdbc.txt", header=TRUE, sep=",")

#Need to convert it to factor
wdbc2=mutate(wdbc, Diagnosis=as.factor(diagnosis))

#Randomize Sequence
set.seed(12345)
wdbc_rand<-wdbc2[order(runif(569)), ]

#Split into training vs. test data
wdbc_train<-wdbc_rand[1:512, ]
wdbc_test<-wdbc_rand[512:569, ]


#Create Model
wdbc_model<-C5.0(x=wdbc_train[-2], y=wdbc_train$Diagnosis)

#Evaluate Performance
wdbc_pred <- predict(wdbc_model, wdbc_test)
CrossTable(wdbc_test$Diagnosis, wdbc_pred, prop.chisq = FALSE,
           prop.c = FALSE, prop.r = FALSE, dnn= c('actual diagnosis', 'predicted diagnosis'))
```

Any help or potential things I could be doing wrong here would be extremely appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Can't enter a comment yet (needs 50 reputation points), so I'll enter this here. Code seems correct, but the accuracy is not 100% I think. In 3 cases the prediction is B while the diagnosis is M. You are also using ID as a predictor while training your model, I would remove that as well.

Comment: Removing the ID makes sense. However, I don't see how you get the accuracy as not being 100% for some reason. Every time I run it, it is coming up as 100% correct

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting data manually use `set.seed` (for random occurrence of the train and test datasets so, that you could get perfect data shape and you can train it. What you did is total wrong method coming to train a machine learning model approach.

```
set.seed(123)
wdbc = wdbc.split(splitratio = 0.7) #(here it is 70% of training data and 20% of test data)
```